# DocuSign ask to sign twice on same anchor tag

Tags: docusignapi

This is the json I send to create an envelope within a signer section :

```
'tabs': {
'signHereTabs': [
{
'documentId': '491272',
'anchorString': 'SignHere-1',
'anchorXOffset': '0',
'anchorYOffset': '0.5',
'anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent': 'true',
'anchorUnits': 'inches'
},
{
'documentId': '491380',
'anchorString': 'SignHere-1',
'anchorXOffset': '0',
'anchorYOffset': '0.5',
'anchorIgnoreIfNotPresent': 'true',
'anchorUnits': 'inches'
}
]
```

The document part for clarification :

```
"documents": [
      {
        "documentBase64": "",
        "name": "EN_Agreement_changing_employment_conditions_Demo2.pdf",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "documentId": "493490"
      },
      {
        "documentBase64": "",
        "name": "EN_Agreement_on_the_use_of_leave_in_kind_Demo2.pdf",
        "fileExtension": "pdf",
        "documentId": "493081"
      }
    ]
```

It asks me to sign twice the first document on "SignHere-1" label, any ideas ?

I tried to change in many ways the json structure but nothing is applying to only one specific document, it applies to the whole envelope.

Answer (score 4):

I think this is happening because you are defining two different tabs with the same anchor string. When you use an anchor string to place a tab, the tab will be placed at all of the locations where the anchor string appears across all of the documents in an envelope. There's no need to specify the `documentId` field when you use anchor tagging so my guess is that it's being ignored and both tabs are appearing in the same document. I would suggest using different anchor strings for each tab or removing one of your tab definitions in the JSON and seeing if that helps. That might clean up the document and help with your issue.

Comment: This is correct. You can contact DocuSign Customer Support to have the Anchor Tag Population Scope changed to "Document" so that you can limit the scanning by specifying the documentId but using different anchor tags would be simpler unless your use case specifically requires you to have the same anchor string